# Adobe Analytics Segments API auth issue with node.js client

Tags: javascript, node.js, analytics, adobe-analytics, segments

I'm facing an authorization issue trying to use Segments APIs via a node.js client.
Stop beating around the bush, below the part of it which manages the POST request and the authorization via the x-wsse headers:

```
var now = new Date();
var options = {
     method: "POST",
     hostname: "api3.omniture.com",
     path: "/admin/1.4/rest/?method=Segments.Get",
     json: true,
     headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Content-Length" : Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(body)),
            "x-wsse": 'UsernameToken Username="[username]:[company]", PasswordDigest="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==", Nonce="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", Created="'+now+'"'
     }
};
```

As you see, I'm trying to replicate the x-wsse generated by the API Explorer, dynamically specifying the Created timestap via Date() JS class.
Node client is reporting me this error:
**{"error":"Bad Request","error_description":"Unable to validate authentication.","error_uri":null}**

I suppose the x-wsse PasswordDigest and Nonce values also continuously change at every request while here I put them static.
If this was the reason for the issue, how dynamically insert also those parameters in the x-wsse header ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Riccardo. Did you ever run into an "Invalid created timestamp" error? I'm experimenting with the Adobe Analytics API, and am using the exact same parameters that the Adobe API explorer outputs, but I'm still getting that error.

Comment: @knoll be sure to submit your request in UTC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `PasswordDigest` and `Created` values are also dynamically generated, because they are based on the value you generate.  I don't know node.js well enough to show you a node.js example, but here is a php example for what I do, with some comments:

```
$username='user:company';
$secret='12345'; // api shared secret key for the user
// The nonce should be a universally unique value. I use a timestamp based value and prefix with a namespace to help make it unique, because AA request digests have to be unique across everybody everywhere ever
$nonce = 'FOO_'.dechex(time());
// datetime stamp in ISO 8601 date format (e.g. '2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00')
$nonce_ts = date('c');
// Adobe expects the PasswordDigest to be a concatenated string value of the nonce, datetimestamp, and api key. They expect it to be hashed (sha1) and then base64 encoded
$digest = base64_encode(sha1($nonce.$nonce_ts.$secret));
$server = "https://api.omniture.com";
$path = "/admin/1.4/rest/";
$rc=new SimpleRestClient();
$rc->setOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-WSSE: UsernameToken Username=\"$username\", PasswordDigest=\"$digest\", Nonce=\"$nonce\", Created=\"$nonce_ts\""));
```

Comment: @RiccardoMalesani btw looks like Adobe does have a [node sdk](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/marketing-cloud-node-sdk) that might be helpful to reference (or just use..not sure what your ultimate situation is!)